# Necesito recuperar un atributo distinto al de value de un select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Debo enviar los datos de mi atributo tel a input

Mi Html

```
<select tipo="i" placeholder="" required="required" class="form-control" id="selCliente">
<option hidden="">Clientes</option>
<option value="5" tel="375">NOMBRE</option>
<option hidden="">Clientes</option>
<option value="9" tel="375">NOMBRE 2</option></select>
```

[image: JS]
Input

```
<input type="text" class="input100" id="txtTelefono" tipo="i" placeholder="Telefono" required>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverFlow! Porfavor, trata de explicar un poco mejor en que necesitas ayuda, que errores te da y que has provado para solucionarlo,

Comment: No existe un atributo `tipo=""` en un **select**, ni un atributo `tel=""` en un **option** o de dónde te basas para realizar tal cosa?

Comment: Eso atributo los uso para validad la seguridad del formulario antes de hacer una insert a mi BD. Aun asi ya resolvi el problema, Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es necesario que uses el this con que accedas al objecto y busques el value ya te sirve.

```js
$("#selCliente").on('change', function(){
 $("#txtTelefono").val($("select option:selected").attr('tel'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select tipo="i" placeholder="" required="required" class="form-control" id="selCliente">
<option hidden="">Clientes</option>
<option value="5" tel="375">NOMBRE</option>
<option hidden="">Clientes</option>
<option value="9" tel="375">NOMBRE 2</option></select>

<input type="text" class="input100" id="txtTelefono" tipo="i" placeholder="Telefono" required>
```

Comment: Si observas con atención el OP requiere enviar lo que esta en el atributo tel="" no el value, aunque no creo que eso sea posible.

Comment: Lo que necesito postear en el input es el atributo "tel" no el "value"

Comment: @CarlosFloresGléz editado para coger el tel

Answer (score 5):

Podrías utilizar el método `attr()` de `jquery` para obtener el atributo llamado tel, algo como esto:

```js
$( "#selCliente" ).change(function() {
  var tel = $("option:selected",this).attr("tel");
  $("#txtTelefono").val(tel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select tipo="i" placeholder="" required="required" class="form-control" id="selCliente">
<option hidden="">Clientes</option>
<option value="5" tel="375">NOMBRE</option>
<option hidden="">Clientes</option>
<option value="9" tel="375">NOMBRE 2</option></select>

<input type="text" class="input100" id="txtTelefono" tipo="i" placeholder="Telefono" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola creo que seria así:

```
var tel=$('#selCliente > option:selected').attr('tel');
$('#txtTelefono').val(tel);
```

Mira a ver si eso te funciona, en resumen tienes que buscar el `option` de ese `select` que posee el tipo `selected`.
Un saludo